# Coldfusion SQL Error

Tags: sql, postgresql, coldfusion

We have a script that dynamically loops through form elements and creates an INSERT statement for our PostgreSQL database.  I'm escaping all single quotes from field values but the query itself still fails.  BUT, if I run the query directly in pgAdmin, it works!  I am lost as to why.

```
<cfset queryfields = "--already defined--">
<cfset queryvalues = "" />
 <cfloop list="#fieldList#" delimiters="," index="f">
 <cfif StructKeyExists(form, f)>
 <cfset queryvalues = queryvalues & "'" & Replace(form[f], "'", "\'", "all") & "'," />
 </cfif>
 </cfloop>
 <!--- Remove trailing commma --->
 <cfset queryvalues = Left(queryvalues, len(queryvalues) - 1) />

<cftransaction>
 <cfquery name="qInsertOrder" datasource="#DSN#">
 INSERT INTO foo_trans (#queryfields#)
 VALUES(#queryvalues#)
 </cfquery>
</cftransaction>
```

**INSERT INTO paypal_trans (TransDate,mc_gross,address_status,payer_id,tax,address_street,payment_status,charset,address_zip,first_name) VALUES('08/22/2011','50.00','confirmed','ABCD4321','0.00','1 Main Road','Completed','windows-1252','10505','Bob O\'Malley') ----------------------------- Error Executing Database Query. (ERROR: syntax error at or near "08")**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> (ERROR: syntax error at or near "08")

CF automatically doubles (escapes) single quotes in cases like yours to help prevent sql injection. So the final VALUES clause sent to the database is actually more like this. Notice each single quote is doubled?

```
    VALUES(''08/22/2011'', ..
```

If that is indeed the problem, PreserveSingleQuotes() will fix it. However, it also reverses CF's automatic sql injection protection. Since you are treating all of the values as strings anyway, you may as well try using cfqueryparam instead. You do not get much in the way of type checking. But you can still loop through the fields dynamically, while maintaining sql injection protection. Possibly boosting performance as well.

**UPDATE**: Also with cfqueryparam, you should not have to worry about manually escaping single quotes anymore.

**UPDATE:** To use cfqueryparam, populate an array with the existing fields to insert.Then loop through the array to generate your `VALUES` clause. I made a few assumptions, but this should produce the desired results.

```
<!--- determine the fields to insert --->
<cfset fieldArray = arrayNew(1)>
<cfloop list="#fieldList#" delimiters="," index="f">
 <cfif StructKeyExists(form, f)>
    <cfset arrayAppend(fieldArray, f)>
 </cfif>
</cfloop>


...
<!--- loop through array to generate VALUES clause --->
VALUES 
(
<cfloop from="1" to="#arrayLen(fieldArray)#" index="x">
    <!--- append separator when needed --->
    <cfif x gt 1>,</cfif>
    <cfqueryparam value="#FORM[fieldArray[x]]#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
</cfloop>
)
```

Comment: The problem is that I cannot type out the individual fields and variables for the query for reasons I won't get into.  Otherwise I would have used `cfqueryparam` in an instant and not have had this issue.

Comment: You should not need to. Just make everything a cf_sql_varchar. You lose type checking, but that is essentially what you are doing now anyway. Other than that, the concept is the same. Give me a minute to show an example.

Answer (score 3):

use `PreserveSingleQuotes()` - http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-6cbf.html

Comment: It does work. But it also opens queries to sql injection even more. So if possible, go with `cfqueryparam` instead.

Comment: `PreserveSingleQuotes()` leaves var values with a single quote unescaped, and it causes a SQL crash all the same.

Comment: @Angry - Re: *"leaves var values with a single quote unescaped*" What do *you* mean by escaping? `PreserveSingleQuotes` just prevents CF from automatically doubling single quotes after the fact. You are still responsible for constructing a properly escaped SQL string to begin with. Does your new SQL string run in pgAdmin?

Comment: The SQL runs fine in pgAdmin.

Answer (score 0):

What is the datatype of the column "TransDate"? Perhaps there's an issue with data type conversion?